Column name become row in CSV export from SSRS
I have report in SSRS that when i try to export it in CSV, somehow the column name become row, why and how can i fix that? i dont know where the setting to fix that
a help would be very much appreciated. thanks!

what exactly are you after? Do you want the header line or do NOT want any header lines on your csv?

Whenever you export in csv it results like this:
Report Output:
Coumn1   Column2
1        1
2        3
3        5

Csv:
Column1, Coumn2
1,1
2,3
3,5

But If you have mistakenly added the Header/Label of the table as part of the grouping, the result would be like this:
Column1,Coumn2,1,1
Column1,Coumn2,2,3
Column1,Coumn2,3,5

